# play sound & run timer using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, timer

i try to play sound  with the below code, but it does not play sound, so i feel sad and finally felt to ask here for your help.

**Script**

```
            $(function() {  
             $('#btn_start').on('click', function(event){

                    event.preventDefault();
                   play_sound('mp3');
                return false;
              });


           //------------------------
           function play_sound(sound)
             { 
                // This next line will get the audio element
                // that is adjacent to the link that was clicked.
                var song = $(this).next('audio').get(0);
                if (song.paused)
                  song.play();
                else
                  song.pause(); 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create a little class like this  :

The duration cannot be get in Javascript (actually not implemented on every browsers, you must set this value for each "songs")

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XYevE/4/

(nota: this is just an example, developped very fast...:))

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="btn_start">PLAY</a>
<div id="timer"><span>click play</span></div>
<div id="ms">
    Before callback:
    <span id="mins"></span>:
    <span id="secs"></span>
</div>
<audio id="audiosource">
    <source src="http://www.cumfortitudine.com/vvdemo/assets/js/actions/vquery.vdemo/scenes/assets/sound/hans-zimmer-injection.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> 
</audio>
```

Javascript:

```
    function myApp() { 
      this.paused = false;
      this.paused = true // set pause to true (stop)
      this.isactive = false; // countdown is active
      this.duration = 0; // set duration to 0 (get via audio DOM)
      return this.observer(); // call and return the "observer" method of the "myApp" class
    }

    myApp.prototype.observer = function() { // observer method
      var self = this; // set this to self (this is the current instance of this class)

      $('#btn_start').on('click', function(event){ // where an user click on "btn_start"
        event.preventDefault();
        self.play('mp3'); // call the play method and store the state in a public var
        self.countdown(self.onEnd); //parameter is the callback when the audio is finished
        self.isactive = true;
      });
      return this; // return this instance
    };

    myApp.prototype.play = function() { // play method
      var song = document.getElementById('audiosource');
      this.duration = song.duration;
      if (this.paused === true)
      {
        $('#btn_start').html('PAUSE');
        console.log('set play song');
        song.play();
        this.paused = false;
      }
      else
      {
        $('#btn_start').html('PLAY');
        console.log('set pause song');
        song.pause();
        this.paused = true;
      }
      return this;
    };

    myApp.prototype.countdown = function(duration, callback) { // countdown method
      var self = this, // class instance
           countdown = null, // countdown
           ctx = null; // setIntervall clearer
           timer = this.duration * 1000; // timer in milliseconds

      if (this.isactive === true) // if this method yet called
      {
        return false;
      }
      countdown = function() {
        if (timer <= 0)
        {
           self.isactive = false; // reset
           clearInterval(ctx);
           callback.call(this);
           return false;
        }
        if (self.paused === false) // if not in pause
        {
          timer -= 250;
          var mins = parseInt((timer / 1000) / 60);
          var secs = parseInt((timer / 1000) - mins * 60);
          $('#mins').html(mins);
          $('#secs').html(secs);
          $('#timer > span').html(timer.toFixed(2));
        }
      };
      ctx = setInterval(countdown, 250);
    };

    myApp.prototype.onEnd = function() {
      // when the audio is finish..
     alert ('end of the song');
    };

;$(function() {
  new myApp();
});
```

Comment: I will comment for help

Comment: I will create a fiddle (i have fix some bug)

Comment: Vote up and confirm this issue.

Comment: Ok i see the bug, wait

Comment: A function "countdown" check if you are at the end of the song and call the callback method.
If you click on the button while the song running, i set true to the public variable "paused". The "countdown" function don't execute the instructions if this variable is === to true. 
Final version : http://jsfiddle.net/XYevE/5/

Comment: can you please provide me an logic to implement Mute/unmute functionality to this question as i updated my fiddle  code here(http://jsfiddle.net/rhy5K/25/) ?   Hope you can help me with this